# How to automatically set configuration in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is there any option to set auto configuration in WebStorm (latest version 2020.1)?

Like if I store all the required run configuration details in a file, when I open the WebStorm it should automatically set the run configuration.

Is there any way to do that? Any suggestion here please.

[image]

Comment: Well ... open `workspace.xml` file from `PROJECT_ROOT\.idea` folder (this is where project settings are stored) and look for `<component name="RunManager" selected="XXX">` kind of line -- that `XXX` will be the internal name of the selected Run/Debug Configuration.

Comment: I suggest you do this: have some test project and create at least 2 Run/Debug Configurations of the desired type (or even different types). Select the desired one in that drop down. Close WebStorm (so it saves the configs) and go to the `PROJECT_ROOT\.idea` folder and look at those files. P.S. If you use "shared" Run/Debug Configuration then it will be stored in a subfolder; non-shared ones are stored in the same `workspace.xml` file (search for `<configuration name="XXX"` sort of line)

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you so much:)